# Get csv from url -> convert into utf-16 txt-> download link

Tags: csv, encoding, google-apps-script, utf-16

Firstly, I apologise if my question is vague or doesn't make sense. I'm very inexperienced in working with the web.

Basically, I have a google spreadsheet which I published as csv link:
[Here is the link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR7giEwAym5W8D-FX9I13fJo3xDS7QkGWAzi1c9WT8hkPx1R5qbr-3PicaW7kxegFywMytm1NOmqBdZ/pub?gid=1199024705&single=true&output=csv)

I need to do 2 things with this:

1. Convert the current file(.csv in utf-8) to .txt in utf-16
2. Provide a download link

It would be nice ideal if I can do this through the google script but I'm not sure how to do this. Otherwise, if someone could help me to make a javascript to do this, I'd really appreciate it. I have hardly any knowledge of html, but can read some basic javascript code. An example in jsfiddle would be even better.

Comment: You will find this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39339309/read-data-from-csv-like-file-in-google-apps-script) helpful when you are just starting. You can also use the [built-in parser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parseCsv(String,Char)) from utilities.

Comment: Thank you the post is helpful

Comment: If you find this helpful, I will make an official answer.