# How to fetch a CSV file from API in google sheets?

Tags: database, api, google-sheets, scripting

I am new to API and google script, so please bare with me.
How do i fetch a CSV file through an API in the right format.

Through UrlFetchApp i was able to fetch the data, but in the wrong format, since the data is not seperated into cells.

```
    function callNumbers() {

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.statbank.dk/v1/data/VG2/CSV?valuePresentation=Default&allowVariablesInHead=true&K%C3%98RART=1000&M%C3%86NGDE4=0070&Tid=2020K3%2C2020K2%2C2020K1");
  
  var data = response.getContentText()
  Logger.log(data);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue([data]);
  
}
```

How do i separate the data into rows (defined by line breaks) and column (defined by the semicolon)?

Please help I am so Lost!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [read data from csv-like file in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39339309/read-data-from-csv-like-file-in-google-apps-script)